# MySql (XAMPP) sometimes has no data in table

Tags: php, mysql

I use MYSQL, PHP 7.2 and MVC architecture but sometimes after inserting data into invoice_table table, invoice_table shown as an empty table, after couple minutes data will come back again.

Comment: Sorry but we can't fix invisible problems with invisible code in environments we cannot see and have zero knowledge about, from a vague one-line description of what appears to be an intermittent fault (but is probably really something else entirely) without any hard evidence provided about specific behaviour. Can **you** fix problems with things you've never seen and have no info about? If so please tell us the secret! We are not mind-readers, clairvoyants or x-ray vision specialists. Please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider updating your question.Thanks

Comment: it is not invisible, a simple insert for data with PDO and after that a simple SELECT for getting data, but my table is empty.

Comment: The problem is invisible to **us**, reading your post. That was my point. How do you expect to fix something for which we have no specific information? This isn't a standard problem. Simply running an insert and then a select would not normally produce this behaviour. There must be something strange in your environment - either a mistake in your setup, or in your code, or it could be that actually you're just seeing symptoms of a different issue entirely. You'll have to do more investigation yourself, since we don't have any access to your particular environment.

Comment: This code is not PDO for starter

Comment: We didn't request _only_ code. And this isn't even all the code either (where's the SELECT bit you mentioned?). Read the comments again. We'd like to help you, in theory, but we **can't** at the moment. There isn't enough info to show the actual problem occurring (and some of your info is inaccurate - e.g. mention of PDO). It's not just us though - if you need further guidance please read the official help pages: [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to Create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The issue is not with the people who answer you, the issue is in your quesition.
1) If you get something in your catch part, what do you get, and where is it?
2) You say that SOMETIMES after inserting, SO. If there is something in the table you are inserting to already, and you see an empty table the issue is simple you are not selecting your records properly to view it. Try viewing the table directly in PHPMy admin and check SQL query that shows your table.

Comment: Your question is missing following parts:
1) Structure of your table
2) What you are trying to insert
3) What do you get as response when you insert it
4) What is in the table you are working with
5) How you are viewing the table

Answer (score 2):

My Problem is solved by RESTARTING MySql service and thanks to @ADyson and @Your_Common_Sense for Helping me :|.
real Thanks to @Undry.